# pointers to structs inside union: how to initialize and retrieve struc values

Tags: c

I have the following simple code. I am trying to understand how I can use structs inside unions and how I can retrieve contents of struct variables in connection with unions.

Here is a small sample code I have written. I want to retrieve the "Maker" struct variables from this code. How should I correctly do it? My code here results in segmentation fault.

**Here is the updated code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>   

typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int *wheels;
}CarVendor;
typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int *wheels;
    int seats;
}BusVendor;

typedef union{
    CarVendor *carvendor;
    BusVendor *busvendor;
}Maker;
typedef struct{
    Maker *carType;
}Car;
typedef struct{
    Maker *busType;
}Bus;
typedef union{
    Car *car;
    Bus *bus;
}Vehicle;

void fillDetails(Vehicle *vehicle, int type){
    if(type == 0){
        vehicle->car->carType->carvendor->name = "car";
        int wheel = 4;
        vehicle->car->carType->carvendor->wheels = &wheel;
    }
    if(type ==1){
        vehicle->bus->busType->busvendor->name = "bus";
        int wheel = 6;
        vehicle->bus->busType->busvendor->wheels = &wheel;
        vehicle->bus->busType->busvendor->seats = 60;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

Vehicle myvehicle;
fillDetails(&myvehicle, 0); //get car details filled & retrieve the details as "Maker" struct
Maker *maker;
maker = (Maker *) malloc(sizeof(Maker));
maker = myvehicle.car->carType;
printf("Name of car =%s", maker->carvendor->name);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why are you using `struct *` rather than just `struct`.  That will make memory management a nightmare.

Comment: where exactly do you mean?

Comment: You're on a wild run. Your code is heavily un-initialized full of dangling pointers. First allocate the memory dynamically then start accessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want everything to be on the heap?

If you really want to, you need to malloc memory for ALL the structures that you've got pointers to (or at least the ones you want to access, e.g. from `fillDetails`), and clean up afterwards. Your union, e.g. `Maker`, essentially just says that this pointer can be one of two types, either a `CarVendor`, or a `BusVendor`.

If you want to do this kind of stuff it sometimes makes sense to have a "type" distinguisher in the structure, such that the code looking at it later knows which type the pointer has. Here's an example:

```
typedef struct a_t_ { /*...*/ } a_t;
typedef struct b_t_ { /*...*/ } b_t;

typedef enum mytype_t_ {a, b} mytype_t;
typedef struct foo_t_ {
    mytype_t type_of_the_below;
    union {
        a_t *a;
        a_t *b;
    };
} foo_t;
```

Again, notice that you need to malloc the memory for the `Maker` before you access it from fillDetails, not after.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>   

typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int *wheels;
}CarVendor;
typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int *wheels;
    int seats;
}BusVendor;

typedef union{
    CarVendor *carvendor;
    BusVendor *busvendor;
}Maker;
typedef struct{
    Maker *carType;
}Car;
typedef struct{
    Maker *busType;
}Bus;
typedef union{
    Car *car;
    Bus *bus;
}Vehicle;

void fillDetails(Vehicle *vehicle, int type){
    if(type == 0){
        vehicle->car->carType->carvendor->name = "car";
        int wheel = 4;
        vehicle->car->carType->carvendor->wheels = &wheel;
    }
    if(type ==1){
        vehicle->bus->busType->busvendor->name = "bus";
        int wheel = 6;
        vehicle->bus->busType->busvendor->wheels = &wheel;
        vehicle->bus->busType->busvendor->seats = 60;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Vehicle myvehicle;
    myvehicle.car = (Car*) malloc(sizeof(Car));
    myvehicle.car->carType = (Maker*)malloc(sizeof(Maker));
    myvehicle.car->carType->carvendor = (CarVendor*) malloc(sizeof(CarVendor));
    fillDetails(&myvehicle, 0); //get car details filled & retrieve the details as "Maker" struct
    Maker *maker = NULL;
    maker = myvehicle.car->carType;
    printf("Name of car =%s\n", maker->carvendor->name);
    free(myvehicle.car->carType->carvendor);
    free(myvehicle.car->carType);
    free(myvehicle.car);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's how you can more safely do it on the stack...

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>   

typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int wheels;
}CarVendor;
typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int wheels;
    int seats;
}BusVendor;

typedef union{
    CarVendor carvendor;
    BusVendor busvendor;
}Maker;

typedef struct{
    Maker carType;
}Car;

typedef struct{
    Maker busType;
}Bus;
typedef union{
    Car car;
    Bus bus;
}Vehicle;

void fillDetails(Vehicle *vehicle, int type){
    if(type == 0){
        vehicle->car.carType.carvendor.name = "car";
        int wheel = 4;
        vehicle->car.carType.carvendor.wheels = wheel;
    }
    if(type ==1){
        vehicle->bus.busType.busvendor.name = "bus";
        int wheel = 6;
        vehicle->bus.busType.busvendor.wheels = wheel;
        vehicle->bus.busType.busvendor.seats = 60;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Vehicle myvehicle;
    fillDetails(&myvehicle, 0); //get car details filled & retrieve the details as "Maker" struct
    Maker *maker;
    maker = &myvehicle.car.carType;
    printf("Name of car =%s\n", maker->carvendor.name);
    return 0;
}
```